# Can we add a nudge to use a PowerShell validator when PowerShell code is detected?

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, code, quality-improvement

For a while I have been contributing to Stack Overflow with PowerShell questions and answers. In here I am seeing a lot of questions with code examples that could be automatically resolved (or improved) knowing that there is an official [PowerShell script analyzer](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer) which could technically be invoked as a service: See: https://github.com/TylerLeonhardt/PSSAaaS.

#### Examples

A few examples where the PSScriptAnalyzer rules could have automatically highlighted a potential issue:

- The incorrect use of the automatic variables (like `$Args` and `$Input`),
  see: *[Automated dictionary entry filling in PowerShell from input command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52695908/automated-dictionary-entry-filling-in-powershell-from-input-command-line-argumen/52696301#52696301)*
  and [Passing arguments as array to PowerShell function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58818197/passing-arguments-as-array-to-powershell-function)
- Simple typos could be avoided (initiators aren't always keen in avoiding and correcting them, see e.g. the comments in: *[check if the client's machine is 32 Bit OS or 64 Bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58871835/check-if-the-clients-machine-is-32-bit-os-or-64-bit)*). In general, it will enforce a [minimal, **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
- Known commands (e.g. `Invoke-Expression`) that  easily lead to confusion (and problems), e.g.: *[PowerShell 'Invoke-Expression' command with single quotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588189/powershell-invoke-expression-command-with-single-quotation)*.
- [Possible Incorrect Comparison With Null](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/1021) (e.g. *[Comparing 2 lists in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58691946/comparing-2-lists-in-powershell)*) which unfortunately also happens a lot in *answers* as well (which also could be possibly automatically avoided)
- ...

<sub>PSScriptAnlayzer currently has almost 60 built-in rules with clear results, see: `Get-ScriptAnalyzerRule` and [PSScriptAnalyzer deep dive – Part 4 of 4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/psscriptanalyzer-deep-dive-part-4-of-4/)) for background.</sub>

Just like the prevention of duplicates with the automatic `Similar questions` pane, the PowerShell code analyzer on recognized PowerShell code (e.g. on the event the <kbd>Review your question</kbd> button is clicked) will likely improve the quality of PowerShell questions (and answers).

Comment: Belongs in the tag wiki.  Which is too bloated, but still doesn't mention this analyzer.

Comment: Yeah, they should add analyzers for every single language